# Passing data from deferred to when

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to pass data from a deferred fail to a when fail.

Below, when all my files have been shown, if any of the files were to fail in self.fileShow I log their names. But is it possible to get all of their names once all deferrers are finished in when?

```
$.when.apply($, $.map(files, function (file, index) {

    return self.fileShow(file, fileSrc, fileNewTemplate)
        .fail(function () {
            console.log(file.name)
        });
})).fail(function () {
    console.log('I want all the file names here that failed')
})
```

Comment: So is the core of your problem that you don't know how to trigger the outer `fail` or that you don't know how to access the file names in both the inner and outer `fail`s?

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer you question title, but offers solution to you problem.
To pass parameters [you could use `deferred.pipe`.](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/)

```
var defer = $.Deferred(),
  filtered = defer.pipe( null, function( value ) {
    return value * 3;
  });

defer.reject( 6 );
filtered.fail(function( value ) {
  alert( "Value is ( 3*6 = ) 18: " + value );
});
```

[Here's example of passing object from fail.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2255-using-jquery-s-pipe-method-to-change-deferred-resolution.htm)